# Many to many Jpa Query Spring boot

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have three mysql tables with a many to many relationship and I am trying to make a Jpa Query on spring boot. The tables are

- product with fields id, name
- extra with fields id, name
- product_extra with fields id, product_id, extra_id

Product table has a many to many relationship with extra table, as a product can have many extras hence the need for product_extra table

Here is the query i would like to include in my project

```
SELECT extra.name 
FROM extra 
INNER JOIN product_extra ON extra_id = extra.id
WHERE product_id = ?;
```

Should i have like a `@ManyToMany` annotation and where should i have it

Comment: Can you explain your use case little better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should. Use `@ManyToMany` to map between Product and Extra.Make sure to use `Set` instead of `List` for the mapping in order to have [better performance](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/). It looks like:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="product")
public class Product{

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "product_extra",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "extra_id")
    )
    private Set<Extra> extras = new HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name="extra")
public class Extra{

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "extras")
    private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<>();
}
```

After mapping them , you can then use JPQL to get a product by id together with its extra by :

```
select p from Product p left join fetch p.extras where p.id = :productId;
```